# Bash Script Statement

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, netcat, mkfifo

I'm trying to figure out what a line means in a bash script file:

```
mkfifo mypipe
nc -l 12345 < mypipe | /home/myprogram > mypipe
```

Here's what I understand: nc -l part creates a server-side like behavior on port 12345, which takes in input from mypipe, which pipes that output to a program, which pipes the program output back into mypipe.

My question is firstly is my analysis correct? Second, what exactly is the mkfifo, like what kind of file is it? I also don't understand what nc -l outputs exactly in order to pipe into the myprogram.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the `< mypipe` is largely irrelevant; it does mean there is a program with the FIFO open for reading, so that the open for `/home/myprogram` returns, but since `nc` is reading on the socket and not from its standard input, the FIFO will eventually fill (maybe after as little as about 4 KiB of data), blocking `/home/myprogram`, and thereafter blocking `nc` too (another 4 KiB or so, which is the capacity of the pipe), which then blocks whatever process is writing to port 12345.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's hardly irrelevant. `nc` reads from both the socket and stdin, and passes the socket input to stdout and stdin input to the socket. You can test it yourself - `echo "GET /" | nc www.google.com 80` will pass `GET /` to Google's server, and pass its response to your screen.

Comment: OK - I'm not sure I understand what `nc` does, then.  It is nominally `netcat`, but `cat` doesn't read its standard input if it is given a file to read instead (and I assumed that `-l 12345` meant listen on port 12345 and `cat` anything that comes in).  If `nc` is different, so be it; I haven't used it more than once or twice - and that extremely casually.  Treat my previous comments with an appropriate pinch of salt (possibly quite large).  It is an unusual arrangement of I/O, regardless of what `nc` does; it would be interesting to know what `/home/myprogram` does with its standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkfifo` creates a pipe file. Here, FIFO means "first-in, first-out". Whatever one process writes into the pipe, the second process can read. It is not a "real" file - the data never gets saved to the disk; but Linux abstracts a lot of its mechanisms as files, to simplify things.

`nc -l 12345` will bind to socket 12345 and listen; when it catches an incoming connection, it will pass the standard input to the remote host, and the remote host's incoming data to the standard output.

Thus, the architecture here is:

```
remote host -> nc -> regular pipe -> myprogram
myprogram -> mypipe -> nc -> remote host
```

effectively letting myprogram and remote host talk, even though myprogram was designed to read from stdin and write to stdout.

Since the bash pipe (`|`) only handles one direction of communication, you need to make an explicit second pipe to do bidirectional inter-process connection.